# localStorage array.push

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Could someone tell me how to push elements into an array in localStorage?

My code:

```js
  (localStorage.getItem('projects') === null) ? localStorage.setItem('projects', ['proj1', 'proj2', 'proj3']) : '';
  var ItemGet = localStorage.getItem('projects');
  function CreateObject() {
    console.log(ItemGet);
    var Serializable = JSON.parse(ItemGet);
    Serializable.push('proj4');
    console.log(ItemGet);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateObject()">Add Object</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to add something to the storage?

Comment: You don't save back the item to localstorage. And of course `ItemGet` won't be updated, because it's only read one from the localstorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General approach:

```
let old_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('projects'))

let new_data = old_data.push(some_new_data)

localStorage.setItem('projects',JSON.stringify(new_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Say for example you have an array. This is how you can store it in the local storage.

```
let my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
localStorage.setItem('local_val', JSON.stringify(my_array))
```

Now to push any data into the local storage array you have to override by the new data like bellow

```
let oldArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('local_val'))
oldArray.push(1000)
localStorage.setItem('local_val', JSON.stringify(oldArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are hitting is that data stored in `localStorage` has to be a string. You'll have to parse/stringify before settting/getting anything from local storage. If you didn't want to work with strings, you may find something like [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

```
const stuff = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

// Stringify it before setting it
localStorage.setItem('stuff', JSON.stringify(stuff));

// Parse it after getting it
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stuff'));
```

Here is an example of using IndexedDB API from the docs

```
const dbName = "the_name";

var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 2);

request.onerror = function(event) {
  // Handle errors.
};
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;

  // Create an objectStore to hold information about our customers. We're
  // going to use "ssn" as our key path because it's guaranteed to be
  // unique - or at least that's what I was told during the kickoff meeting.
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers", { keyPath: "ssn" });

  // Create an index to search customers by name. We may have duplicates
  // so we can't use a unique index.
  objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });

  // Create an index to search customers by email. We want to ensure that
  // no two customers have the same email, so use a unique index.
  objectStore.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });

  // Use transaction oncomplete to make sure the objectStore creation is
  // finished before adding data into it.
  objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
    // Store values in the newly created objectStore.
    var customerObjectStore = db.transaction("customers", "readwrite").objectStore("customers");
    customerData.forEach(function(customer) {
      customerObjectStore.add(customer);
    });
  };
};
```

There are also other solutions out there like [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) depending on your needs

Comment: Sorry about that. Typo is fixed.

Comment: What part isn't working? Stackoverflow has this blocked and snippets won't work with localstorage if that is what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following assuming that your data is not a multiDimensional array.

```
(localStorage.getItem('projects') === null) ? localStorage.setItem('projects', 
JSON.stringify(['proj1', 'proj2', 'proj3'])) : '';
var ItemGet = localStorage.getItem('projects');
function CreateObject() {
     var Serializable = JSON.parse(ItemGet);
     Serializable.push('proj4');
     localStorage.setItem('projects',JSON.stringify(Serializable));
}
```